# Terraform lists resource as provider during init

Tags: terraform

While creating a custom provider, I am unable to `init` my resources.

My provider is called `shell`. It has a resource called `environment`. I have compiled my provider into a binary. But when I run a `terraform init` on it, it throws an error that the provider `environment` is not found:

```
Provider "environment" not available for installation.

A provider named "environment" could not be found in the official 
repository.
```

Why is it considering a resource as a provider?

Output of `terraform providers` also list the resource as a provider.

```
$ terraform providers

.
├── provider.environment
└── provider.shell
```

Edit:

Adding how the resource is called.

```
provider "shell" {
  ...
}

resource "environment" "env" {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your Terraform code that includes the resource definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terraform, all resources are prefixed with their provider name and an underscore.

The EC2 instance resource is `aws_instance` while the Azure instance is `azurerm_virtual_machine` etc.

So in your case you want to call your resource `shell_environment`.

Comment: Is there a reason for this?

Comment: It's effectively namespacing the resources in a sensible way. So if you have 2 providers with the `instance` resource then they can both be used at the same time as `foo_instance` and `bar_instance`.